# Why is the index.html in my React.js build folder not loading as the Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, create-react-app

**I am develping a Chrome extension using React.js.** I created the project using `create-react-app`. I used npm start to see the app in a browser tab during the development phase. The manifest.json file is also configured. I then created the build using `npm run build` to load the unpacked extension and see how it works in Chrome, **however the popup is empty**. Upon checking the elements in the extension Dev Tools I just see the `div id="root"` with nothing inside.

I saw somewhere regarding adding a `.env` file with `INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false` in it but a build after adding that is not working either.

Interestingly when I built the empty project (with the spinning React logo right after running create-react-app) worked 100% fine when I loaded it as an unpacked extension.

I am using react-router-dom for the pages.

**Why is the index.html in my React.js build folder not loading as the Chrome extension? And how can I solve it?**